# Common mistakes for a Stack Overflow user to avoid?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

In the spirit of all these common mistake questions...

Comment: I think people are going to ding you for posting this on StackOverflow instead of Meta.stackoverflow.com :(

Comment: Apparently no one caught the joke. Oh well.

Comment: We caught on, it was just off topic, the solution to having crap on the front page, is not adding more crap :p

Comment: Asking 'what's your favourite hidden feature in...' questions is definitely a common mistake.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question title that doesn't describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41976/question-title-that-doesnt-describe-the-problem)

Answer (score 9):

Don't post "common mistake" or "hidden feature" questions.

Comment: Why not?  They're perfectly valid questions.  I don't see why learning from others' mistakes should be discouraged.

Comment: I'm quite annoyed by all of the "Common Mistakes in SQL" (instead, ask a specific question about a particular common mistake and how to avoid it, perhaps tagging it "common-mistake") and "Hidden Features in C" (C is a standard...there are no hidden features).

Comment: I disagree.  Someone just learning a language would benefit a great deal by reading about the common pitfalls in that language.  They're also not likely to know of a common mistake to post, or whether or not their own recent blunder was common or not.  I do see why it's annoying when the same person posts eight "common mistake" or "hidden feature" questions in an hour, but I don't think that's reason to get rid of that class of question altogether.

Answer (score 7):

Don't ask duplicate questions...

Answer (score 3):

Associating reputation with skill

Answer (score 2):

Hi All, this is my third stack overflow answer/question.

I love answering and asking questions because we're a smart bunch.

Thanks a lot!

-dlamblin

P.S. Don't answer with any of the obvious answers.

Answer (score 2):

"Why was my question closed when the [favorite programmer cartoon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon)* question is still open?"... wah wah wah etc.

**Or replace the favorite programmer cartoon question with any other question that has been around since the dawn of SO and happens to be open at the moment.*