# Migration time and Close time mixed up

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

Closing a migrated question appends the close time to the "migrated from" message. Either the migrated time should be present all the time (it's currently not there normally) or closing shouldn't mess with the "migrated from" message.

[http://img253.imageshack.us/img253/9128/lieso.png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551680/where-can-i-download-stackoverflow)

[http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/8282/liemso.png](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44653/where-can-i-download-stackoverflow)

So, when was this migrated?

Of course, it **was migrated** 10 hours ago, but it **was closed** 1 hour**s** ago, and SO smashes the migration time with the close time.

<sup>So much for a bounty on this - isn't anyone going to look at this bug?</sup>

Comment: Sent 10 hours ago, arrived 1 hour ago. It's a very slooooooow network connection.

Comment: You know these questions that keep popping up where the post just says "Question is in the title"? I wish this was one of them.

Comment: @balpha: [Question title that doesn’t describe the problem] http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41976/question-title-that-doesnt-describe-the-problem

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41976/question-title-that-doesnt-describe-the-problem

Comment: What's Holly Time Warp?  Is that a reference to traditional Christmas foliage, and its ability to transcend time and space?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18530/closing-a-migrated-question-seems-to-reset-the-migrated-timestamp

Comment: Unless someone answers this or marks the question as [by-design] I'm going to have to "award" the bounty to myself

Comment: I'm guessing (without being able to see the whole database schema) that the migration time is stored in `ClosedTime` (since it's a close reason on the original site), and closing it on the new site overwrites that field

Comment: Reproed on Jan. 16, 2011 (screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/d65l1.png).

Comment: This will be pushed in tomorrow's build.

Answer (score 5):

It was closed and migrated to meta. Along the way it had a deep and meaningful conversation with the Community user (that was taking it to meta) that caused it to re-evaluate it's self worth. It became depressed, took up drinking, had a son, realised he couldn't continue drinking 5 bottles of wine before breakfast and so went into rehab. Recovered, and with a son to think about, he lived a long happy life with the other closed questions that realised there was more to life than meta. Then, when it was his time to go, he made his way back here one last time. Community was waiting for him.

Welcome back, Where can I download stackoverflow?, we've been waiting for you. You're safe now.

Comment: seriously.. no wait... really?

Answer (score 2):

Bumping this, as I think it's actually a bug.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50297/how-do-i-set-a-real-login-password-on-stack-overflow-instead-of-using-openid-cl) which was migrated from SO has now been closed.

The "Migrated from Stack Overflow" message is now showing a time (which it didn't before), and that time is the same as the "closed time".

[image]
<sub>(source: [free-online.co.uk](http://www.forman.free-online.co.uk/images/migrated-time.png))</sub>

Other, open migrated questions aren't showing a time at all.

**UPDATE** 22nd-June-2010 - this is still happening.

Comment: The question could have been migrated 2:59 minutes ago and closed 2:01 minutes ago.

Comment: @Daniel - no. Before I closed it it wasn't showing any time at all. Immediately after I voted to close it showed "0 secs ago". It's only showing "2 mins ago" because that's how long it took me to get the screen shot (don't ask). If you follow the link back to the original question on Stack Overflow it shows (currently) "5 hours ago" (i.e. just over 4 hours before the question was closed)

Comment: Also see - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50319/peer-presure-badge-closed

Comment: If even the serious ChrisF is making freehand circles now, where is this world going!

Comment: @Gnoupi - Freehand circles on meta are mandatory aren't they? :)