# Ability to protect a question from the flags list

Tags: feature-request, moderation, moderator-tools

I have the same issue! Mee toooo!  I tried this but it didn't work.  If you find a solution can you email me at douche@bag.com?  Hi am new android and also same issue please if help can do now thanks.  Is nobody going to answer this?  OMG this is a lifesaver!  Thansk!  Thanks a Billion!!!!!! It worked for me! I'm facing a problem that looks like this, but its substantially different, let me explain in detail.  ddddddddddddddffffffffffffffffssssssssssssssssaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.  I'm trying to do the same thing and I'm wondering if you can pass me part of the code.

We can delete this cruft from the flag list, but if we want to protect the question, we have to skip over and clicky on the mod link, etc etc.  Would be nice to be able to protect a question from the flag, if not access the entire mod menu from the flag list.

Comment: Also still wanting for the ability to directly convert an answer into a question.

Comment: It would be in proper Meta style for *another* mod now to post a "I have the same problem too" answer.

Comment: @Pekka why didn't you answer?

Comment: @Will I considered, but thought I shouldn't because I'm not a mod. But on second thought, it's even *more* fitting if I *do*

Comment: @Pekka **What**. **Have**. **You**. **Done**.

Comment: xoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxxoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAffffffffffffffffffffdddddddddddddssssssssss

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 6):

Dear Will,

I have the same problem. I tried some things others said but they didn't work. Please send me solution to [pekka@gmx.de](http://mailto:pekka@gmx.de)

Thanks,
Pekka

Answer (score 3):

Thank you guys, I figured it out

Comment: Request for new ban reason: *banned until your last answer is improved*!

Comment: Closing this answer as duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41976/question-title-that-doesnt-describe-the-problem