# Automatically protect questions with three or more low-rep-user deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderation, protected-questions

There are a few "automatically protect questions" requests out there, but I'd like to add another twist.

I'd like to request that questions that have three or more deleted answers by users with <50 rep be automatically protected.

The reasoning behind this is that we have lots and lots of "not an answer" flags in the mod queue.  But we cannot protect a question from the mod queue, so we have to open each answer, evaluate if the question needs protecting, then protect it.

This process takes a long time, and can definitely be automated, as the only thing you really need to check is how many new users are posting non-answers or are spamming their awful products.

Comment: So I assume it would also help you (apart from this feature request) if users (with enough rep) who flag such questions also protect them?

Comment: @Felix: Would be nice if they did.  I've only seen that happen *one time*, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok. I did is a couple of times but I was unsure whether I use "my powers" correctly. I will pay more attention now :)

Comment: I even think that all the posts with a year old, with accepted answers should be protected.

Comment: @YOU: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79812/should-we-automatically-protect-questions-that-are-at-least-a-certain-age I agree with Jeff that the "proven track record" is key here.

Comment: @Cody, similar but they didn't mention about accepted answer.

Comment: @YOU Because accepted answers are not a good indicator alone. They do not always indicate that the problem is solved, and they certainly do not impart an indication that there is a problem for accumulating noise.

Comment: If it boiled down to a choice, Will, do you prefer this or [your original suggestion for protection from the dashboard](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76507/ability-to-protect-a-question-from-the-flags-list)? It seems the main argument for automated protection is that we do not have that dashboard functionality, but I am curious if you'd still prefer the automation even if we had the dashboard functionality.

Comment: @Grace & Cody, Well, first, 90% of recently protected question with accepted answer and from '08, '09 ... http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=last30days, and protecting only limit to users with less than 10 reps, limiting to such questions shouldn't have any probem, imho.

Comment: @YOU My first answer on Stack Overflow, back when I had 1 rep, was to a question with an accepted answer. It was the correct answer, it got me 25 reputation from the vote-up and accept. My case is only 2 months, but that's only my case. [Age and acceptance are not indicators of a *need* to be protected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51560/new-users-adding-answers-to-answered-questions/51564#51564), and it can very well present a problem. *Pre-emptitive protection is a very dangerous thing*, and I really do not find it a wise move in any circumstance.

Comment: @Grace, Well, Even if you can't answer that question(25 rep you got) as first one, I am sure you can answer that question as 2nd question :-)

Comment: This is why Will's suggestion here, while I'm still personally against automation, at least it is targetting exactly what protection is meant to target - posts that *get* noise. That is what protection is meant for. If you block legitimate questions that aren't attracting junk, you're just imposing a barrier to new entries for absolutely no reason.

Comment: @YOU It's one thing to tell someone who can't comment "Just answer a couple questions, you'll get enough reputation". You can't do that with a protected question. You're telling someone, "In order to answer questions, you need to answer questions". It's not easy to get started on this site, and if a user finally runs into a question that can show off that user's knowledge, you are denying that user entrance to the community with a big "GO AWAY" sign if it's protected for no good reason. And, at the same time, you're denying the question asker a potentially great answer.

Comment: @GraceNote: I'd prefer the ability to access the mod dashboard.  At least, those options that make sense (those that can be reasonably used with the information available in the mod list.

Comment: @Grace, Imm, I still don't understand why 1+ year ago questions should be first one to get started on SO. There is a lot of recent questions on mainpage to answer it.

Comment: @YOU There's no reason they need to be protected in the first place, either.

Comment: @Grace, reason is simply because there is more spams compare to good answer, IMHO.

Comment: @YOU: One reason to start on old questions could be that you can take all the time you want to answer them. This might be a rare case, but I agree with Grace that a general mechanism is not The Way to Go here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This will be in the next build.  When the third answer on a question from a new (<10 rep) user is deleted, Protection will be triggered automatically from Community.  There is one tweak though: each user only counts once when we're checking deleted (to eliminate the self-answers that should be comments on their own question case).

Let's face it, we love numbers, so let's take a look at Stack Overflow:

This would currently apply to **730** undeleted questions, of which:

- **283** are *already* protected (~39%)
- **7** are closed
- **5** are locked

Here's a random (`newid()`) sampling of 20 of those 447 remaining questions this would apply to:

- [Trying to upload video to facebook using FBConnect for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3104660)
- [Can I use Facebook's fb:friend-selector in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/820421)
- [Javascript Post on Form Submit open a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/178964)
- [Show and hide divs at a specific time interval using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/914951)
- [Cufon line-height is not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1454480)
- [Why is my CalendarExtender getting overlapped when rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/302244)
- [jQuery get select option text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/196684)
- [Add an array of buttons to a GridView in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/775188)
- [Facebook Javascript FB.api - callback not called on error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2874886)
- [NoSuchPortException using RXTX Java library on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274179)
- [Uninstalling demo/trial of Visual Studio 2008 Team System](https://stackoverflow.com/q/615818)
- [jQuery How do you get an image to fade in on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1383870)
- [Jquery Change Height based on Browser Size/Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/838137)
- [How can I make the old region resize adaptively in Java GC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5459559)
- [Has reCaptcha been cracked / hacked / OCR'd / defeated / broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/448963)
- [Stretch and Scale CSS Background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/376253)
- [What can cause "invalid binary" with no email followup from iTunes Connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3433360)
- [Android Emulator won't run application started from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2793956)
- [What are the prerequisites for Facebook stream.publish?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1154742)
- [CREON development advice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1486630)

Comment: So this doesn't apply retroactively, correct? (But would it apply if a fourth/fifth/... answer is deleted on one of those 447 questions?)

Comment: @Hendrik - Correct we're not auto-protecting these at this time, just making it automatic/easier when a moderator (or the community) deletes a low-rep user answer the next time.

Comment: Do you know how happy this new feature makes me? _Very happy_. I wish it were applied retroactively, but either way, it's a great improvement.

Comment: @Nick is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216934/152859) a bug, like I suspect?