# What causes a question to be protected by the Community ♦ user

Tags: support, community-user, protected-questions

I noticed [**this question**](https://serverfault.com/questions/148445/sql-server-restore-a-backup-results-in-an-error) in particular, which has 5 deleted answers on it.  The most recently deleted answer was deleted by a diamond mod 3 minutes prior to the time it was protected by Community ♦

Is there an automated process that causes a question to be protected by Community ♦ instead of a human?  If so, what are the qualifications that it checks for in order apply the protection?

Related:

- [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)
- [Automatically protect questions with three or more low-rep-user deleted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers)

Comment: Reopened, as things have changed, and this is as good as any place to make a canonical FAQ about how this happens.

Comment: related: [Auto-protect questions that get more than N answers from new users in a 24-hour period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226619/auto-protect-questions-that-get-more-than-n-answers-from-new-users-in-a-24-hour) and [How many questions escape community protection because of reputation gained within checked question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238594/how-many-questions-escape-community-protection-because-of-reputation-gained-with)

Comment: @Tim isn't it better be part of the [existing FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) then?

Comment: Sadly, the "FAQ" asks " what is a protected question" and the format doesn't lend itself to ask "when a question get automagically protected"

Answer (score 20):

That specific old question could be protected by the amount of views it generated or the total amount of answers, since protection kicked in whenever a question had over 10 answers or 10,000 views. Whatever happened first.

Right now isn't like that, protection only kicks in:

- when [3 to 20 (depending on site) low reputation users answer a question in the span of 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228805/213575) or,
- whenever [three low reputation users answers are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89971/213575) or,
- whenever [two spam answers are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302235/165773)

Again, whatever happens first. Low reputation users are users below 10 on-site reputation ([excluding association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238296/165773)), which is required to answer a protected question.