# How many answers deleted as spam or rude does it take to automatically protect a question?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, spam, protected-questions, offensive

It takes three deleted answers on a question for the question to be automatically protected.

[Automatically protect questions with three or more low-rep-user deleted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers)

Does the same apply for answers deleted as spam or rude/offensive with flags?

[What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)

Comment: [This post on GD.SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/98811/bending-and-pattern-along-pattern-inkscape/98820#98820) just had a spam answer deleted. By the looks of it, one spam answer isn't enough to protect the question.

Comment: I'm not sure the answers in those linked questions are accurate, the following has two non-answers (neither from the OP) and two spams all spaced months apart and only the second spam today caused a protection: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38886/emi-filter-calculation-in-a-smps/330723#330723

Comment: [they say it takes two spam answers to trigger auto-protection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357942/839601)

Comment: @gnat I'm wondering why this question wasn't answered, but the other one was.

Comment: they probably were too busy so I just added my own answer here with link and quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to spam, according to explanation provided by Stack Exchange team [in this answer at MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357942/839601) two answers trigger auto-protection:

> We also perform a check when the state of an answer is changed, meaning when an answer is deleted... if a question has 2 answers that have been flagged as spam (not offensive), then we automatically protect the question at that time...

As you can see from above quote rude flags don't qualify for 2-answers protection.

Comment: o you know if "flagged as spam" means "received at least one spam flag" or "received enough spam flags to auto delete it" or "received a spam flag that was handmarked helpful" ?

Comment: I think latter two @KateGregory. Or more precisely it is unlikely that auto-protection trigger gets into tiny details like that, this would be poor / fragile design. If done right it should feed from some other subsystem which determines whether post qualifies for -100 rep penalty without getting into exact details of how this subsystem works (separation of concerns)

Comment: ...if you think of it, rep penalty makes a natural border between confirmed spam (not 100% but close enough) and some random flag possibly cast by mistake or even with bad intentions