# Why wasn't this question automatically protected after 7 deleted spam answers?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, spam, protected-questions

I just destroyed a spam user, and noticed that one of their posts, which is to this question:

[Require anonymous user to register to add content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494840/require-anonymous-user-to-register-to-add-content-type)

Is the **seventh** spam answer to be deleted. I looked at the question and noticed it wasn't automatically protected by Community♦ already, so I've gone ahead to protect it myself.

Why wasn't this question automatically protected? According to [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers), a question is auto-protected after three answers from new users are deleted. Did the accounts responsible for the other spam answers somehow escape the low-rep threshold?

Comment: It looks like only two of those answers were deleted as spam and the rest were simply deleted as normal. Dunno if that's relevant.

Comment: Judging by the content of those posts, the users were probably destroyed from their profile pages.

Comment: Does anyone else think the spam posts are ironic, given the question's title?  Maybe someone is trying to make a point. :)

Comment: @BrockAdams I was just scratching my head wondering why that was attracting so much of the absolute *worst* kind of spam.  :)

Comment: What are the dates of spam deletion?

Comment: @random: All in the last three months.

Comment: So it's possible the other spam deleted were before the auto-protect was in place, leaving you with a fresh slate of needing three deleted to trigger it from whenever the commit was pushed

Comment: What's the deal with all the spam answers on that post?  Do people who are interested in `Drupal anonymous user registration` also have a natural affinity for designer hand bags?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Anyone advertising handbags on Stack Overflow obviously has their finger firmly on the pulse of the community.  It is what we crave.

Comment: Lizard bags. :D

Comment: so...many...diamonds...

Comment: Yep, that's one of mine.  My [feature-requests] are all made of pure awesome and win.

Comment: @Wont [tag:status-confirmed]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry this fell off our radar for so long...

But as part of our spam-fighting initiative that's been ramping up for the past few months, this is now implemented. Spam deletions now count towards the threshold at which a post is auto-protected.

Answer (score 25):

For this particular case it appears the owners from the deleted questions were all destroyed - no OwnerUserId = no way to check reputation thresholds.  We will look at adding another threshold around protecting posts with many destroyed users as this could also be a sign of a spam storm / abuse.

Comment: Based on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129996/does-auto-protection-not-work-on-migrated-questions) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142513/auto-protect-does-not-seem-to-kick-in-on-migrated-questions#comment403972_142513) – is there a possibility to add such a check?

Comment: Is this [status-planned] yet? The behavior is the same [as of Feb 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950150/whats-the-best-api-for-automated-forex-trading) - destroyed users don't count toward auto-protection.