# Auto-protect does not seem to kick in on migrated questions

Tags: bug, migrated-questions, protected-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically protect questions with three or more low-rep-user deleted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers)
>   [Why wasn't this question automatically protected after 7 deleted spam answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114136/why-wasnt-this-question-automatically-protected-after-7-deleted-spam-answers)

This question here:

[Is there any way to change the Windows 7 password using the command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/456546)

It should have been auto-protected, since there are already three deleted spam answers on it. Now, I believe two of those were even carried over from Stack Overflow, which is what triggers the bug — they don't count as being deleted on Super User.

In any case, the auto-protecting of migrated questions has always seemed buggy to me, and this is at least one example of that.

Comment: Err, isn't this the same issue [described here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129996/does-auto-protection-not-work-on-migrated-questions)? Presumably those deleted spam answers are all associated with deleted/non-existent-due-to-migration users?

Comment: Haha, dang, I don't even remember asking this. Yes. It's the same problem. But it's still not fixed. Feel free to close this though.