# I cannot believe what I have seen today

Tags: discussion, down-votes, meta, locked-questions

Today, with my best intention, I posted a suggestion to restrict the downvotes (compelling users to justify why they downvote), it got lots of downvotes and reasons: "this has been proposed before lot of times", "it will not work because of this and that", etc. I closed the question (the community does not like it = does not belong here = it should be deleted).

I thought that perhaps I didn't transmit the ideas properly and that's why I tried it again, this time by highlighting my intention of deleting it after reaching -6 (because of not wanting to go against the general feeling). I got various answers and thus wasn't able to delete it. I tried to reply as well as I could; but apparently I wasn't welcome (because people asking something which has been asked before is not welcome) and thus the process was pretty tiring. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191849/giving-reasons-for-downvoting-should-be-mandatory) you have the post.

Finally, I stop seeing the point and decided to transmit it via title and content (it is duplicated, I don't like the answers, I want to delete it, why it is still here?): I don't like what I have seen at all. But, apparently, critics are not welcome either and thus someone made my question/title back to what it was before. I re-edited it, but then one of the moderators locked the question and banned me from editing my own question further?! The content you can see there is not what I want to say.

The most ironical part is that some of the arguments against what I proposed were based on the idea that this wasn't too democratic! Apparently, requesting justifications when downvoting is not democratic; but avoiding someone to say what he wants is perfectly fine (if this someone thinks differently and thus is not welcome).

Yesterday (my first day here in Meta) I wrote [another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191743/actual-value-of-accepted-answers). Despite not having changed this post at all, its ideas seem to be less valid (-2 already) today. How I know that both issues are related; I cannot know, but this is what I think of Meta now (the attitude of a relevant proportion of its users). I am sure that this new question will help me (and anyone else reading it) to get still a better feeling about how are things here.

You can start to downvote now; also, please, feel completely free to change any part of the question which you don't like too much. I will not do any editing, but just to make sure, perhaps you should lock the question right away. This time I will not participate too much; please don't be bothered by this fact at all and just enjoy: upvote each other as much as you can while downvote the question.

**UPDATE**

Perhaps I have over-reacted a bit, but don't like when actions are taken without my consent. Perhaps I shouldn't have edited my question, but a nice warning would have been enough (rather than modifying what I wrote without my permission). Other than this bit, I am pretty happy to recognise that people here have proven to be tolerant and understanding with a new member who has shown a somehow-aggressive attitude :) I will let the text of my original question, but apologise for the tone and highlight that does not reflect accurately my opinion about Meta.

**UPDATE 2**

I don't know what to say? How is everything so easily misunderstood here? Anyway... I will not change the update above but don't think that will come back either (not my style).

**UPDATE 3 (4 months later update)**

I thought that nobody cared about this post since pretty long time ago but today I met someone proving me wrong and that's why I am back. The whole point of this post was showing my disagreement when I wasn't able to do what I wanted with something I wrote (nothing to hide; just realised that wasn't the feeling of the community and thought that better deleting it). When I wrote this post, I was relatively new in SO and wasn't too aware about the overall rules, expectations, etc. (much less about the Meta ones). Now I accept certain things without any problem (although still not everything).

I do agree in that some moderation has to be present; and that, some times, this moderation needs to be executed without any discussion (e.g., spam); but I don't think that censoring certain type of texts should be defended in SO/Meta. For example: I can easily get involved in discussions not related at all with the given question; although, most of the times I do that to help some people to understand the implications of their behaviour, what I think that is good for Meta/SO. I do accept no-discussing censure, but I think that a different approach would be better in these contexts; I would welcome any suggestion from the moderators (e.g,. "ey!, this tone is a bit aggressive here; reword this comments or start a private; etc. If you don't take care of this, we would do it for you").

In summary: the whole point of this update is clarifying what moved me to write this post (and to vandalise my previous one): showing my disagreement with certain SO/Meta rules regarding moderation. My opinion now is a bit different (I guess that I am more used to see this kind of things) and I do think that my vandalising attempt was a bit childish (but I thought in this way also when I wrote this post. Note that I rarely behave childishly, but take freedom-restriction and censure related issues pretty personally; on the other hand, I do take full responsibility for any action and correct any problem ASAP).

Comment: Careful. You could get post banned.

Comment: @ColeJohnson it would prove my point. I don't really care. Unless seeing lots of changes, I am not interested in Meta anymore. Don't like censure. Thanks for the upvote, honestly I wasn't expecting any.

Comment: @varocarbas: censure? You're the one wanting to delete your content...

Comment: "avoiding someone to say what he wants is perfectly fine" - I don't understand that. Didn't you get to post your idea(s)? Didn't you get feedback on that?

Comment: @Mat as you rightly said, it is my content. I can do whatever I want with it. If you avoid me to express my opinion, you are censuring me.

Comment: @Mat as said, I was happy until I decided to something you don't like and then you forced me to not do it.

Comment: Censure != censor. Just sayin'.

Comment: I wanted to edit my post and you made it back to what it was. This was the censuring part. I was only transmitting an idea and you didn't allow me to do that.

Comment: You attempted to censor everyone who posted anything on that question by deleting the whole thing. Never at any point did we try to stop you saying anything you wanted to say (we did stop you unsaying something you'd already said but thats different

Comment: @RichardTingle sorry to say. I didn't try to delete the question after I realised that was impossible (because of having answers). I accept it to be there. It was duplicate so what was the point of maining my text/title (already explained somewhere else)? In any case I would have accepted any indication, but nobody said me anything, just banned me.

Comment: Much like real politics meta requires a thick skin, my first question went really badly (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178750/why-do-stackexchange-sites-remove-whitespace) but I got over it and now quite enjoy the frank style of meta (although I still feel meta voting requires a revamp)

Comment: @RichardTingle I do understand that and, honestly, don't share it (no bad feeling, it is just not my style). I don't have any problem with anything I have seen; except this thing of thinking that a different idea or a repeated is something bad (and going all against one) and, on top of everything, not having anyone coming to me and saying "ey, don't do this editing"; just correcting what I wrote and when I edited it againt, blocking me: this is not the right way to do anything.

Comment: Technically you weren't blocked; we all were. Its locked to give us all some time to cool off. Regarding the original edit remember you licence the content to stack exchange, its becomes community owned. Its like if I started a wikipedia page, I couldnt then go back and vandalise it without a backlash

Comment: @ColeJohnson It is *extremely* difficult to get question-banned on Meta. You must be a *very* persistent troll. The team [recognizes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109263/question-banning-should-work-differently-on-meta) that question banning should work differently here because of how differently votes work. Please don't try to scare people. Question bans are meant to address serious problems, not just people with unconventional ideas.

Comment: @CodyGray now my ideas are unconventional... :)

Comment: @CodyGray so that's why Telkitty still exists...

Comment: Anyway... I am happy to have posted this question and have got these replies. I am really sorry for having doubt of the community good faith (I will edit my question right now). I don't like at all the editing without my permission part; a simple conversation ("ey don't do that") would have been enough to change my mind, but I don't like impositions, neither think that give anything at all.

Comment: In response to your edit about preferring to be *told* what to do, I'd just point out that while this makes sense, most people prefer it the other way around. Why bother me about it, when you can just do it yourself *for* me? It's like if I have a typo in one of my answers. I don't want someone to leave me a comment, I just want them to edit and fix it.

Comment: This is a collaborative site and the content that we publish is  cc-wiki, that's the basic premise. I've learned a lot from other fellow's edits and regularly leave feedback in my edit summaries and this is *conversation*. The system has been perfected and works as nothing that internet has seen. There are limits, of course, but here we are all free to edit whatever we think needs improvement. Take more time to digest the Way of the Stack ;)

Comment: @brasofilo thanks for sharing your impressions. In any case, if you read my last update (UPDATE 3 (4 months later update)) you would understand that I am quite aware about how the site work. This was written 4 months ago (when I was starting in SO/Meta) and even by then I accepted that this was something which I wrote in the moment as the result of a bit-childish behaviour; thus not truly reflecting what I thought (even by then). If keeping whatever I write makes Meta/SO happy, excellent. But you should understand the right context while talking with a person.

Comment: @brasofilo I have updated my Meta profile. Please, feel free to let me know about your impressions on it. I hope that now things are clearer and that there will not be any future misunderstanding, that is: you (or any other person) will contribute positively to relevant-to-Meta discussions (don't think that this post, at least now, belongs to this group).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It was already explained to you why you are not allowed to delete the question (because it already has received upvoted answers), and why deleting a question just because people disagree with you doesn't make sense. Bart's and Yannis's comments are particularly succinct and powerful in making this point:

> Because this is a Q&A. You propose something, and then other users get to express their views in answers. That's how this site works. There is no point in continuously making proposals and then deleting them if the votes are not to your liking.
>   –[Bart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191849/giving-reasons-for-downvoting-should-be-mandatory#comment597534_191849)

> There's nothing logical about deleting this question. The downvotes are there to show every future reader that the community strongly disagree with the premise of your question. That's a useful datapoint, and it doesn't say anything about the quality of the discussion or you, personally.
>   –[Yannis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191849/giving-reasons-for-downvoting-should-be-mandatory#comment597595_191849)

So then you tried to beat the system by vandalizing your own question, removing all the *content* and replacing it with "delete me"-style *nonsense*. We don't allow that from the original poster any more than we would allow it from some random spammer. So someone rolled that back.

I cannot imagine why [that offended you so greatly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191849/giving-reasons-for-downvoting-should-be-mandatory#comment597648_191849). He wasn't putting words into your mouth or anything. He didn't even make substantive edits to the content of your question. He just put back exactly what you had originally written.

But even if he *had* made edits to the content of your post, like improving the grammar or fixing the formatting, that would have been OK, too. Like the moderator who locked your question said, this site (like all Stack Exchange sites) is collaboratively edited. Anyone can make or suggest edits to improve posts. [That is in the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

The moderator stepped in and locked the question because there was an *edit war* going on. You had tried to vandalize your question, someone had rolled it back and complained, etc. It didn't look like that process was going to stop. So in order to ensure that you listened, the moderator put the question back to its original, non-vandalized state and locked it. That way, if you want to contest that, you would have to do what you've done: ask a new question to discuss it.

Aside from all of that, I have a hard time understanding why it shocks you that people are relatively unlikely to approve of brand new revolutionary ideas that go completely against the fabric and foundation of the entire system we have set up here. Obviously we [mostly] like the current system, or we wouldn't have put so much time and energy into creating, defending, and improving it. Therefore, we don't want to make fundamental changes to it that we think violate its spirit or essence. We also get fatigued by reading the same suggestions over and over from people about things we've already discussed to death. We wonder why those people don't just go back and read those previous discussions first, before making their own arguments and trying to pass them off as completely novel. They don't seem that way to us.

But even if we're completely wrong and your revolutionary ideas are right, it should still not surprise you that we do not react positively. History is littered with examples of this. If people could have downvoted Che Guevara, they would have. Sometimes, it takes enduring a bit of opposition to effect real change. If you believe strongly in your arguments, you should stick by them. It's not like downvotes really mean anything anyway. (Other than disagreement, which has already been adequately explained to you.)

Comment: You know what I hate the most? That this is a right answer.

Comment: You should have done something so good in my previous question and I would have awarded it to you. In any case, I wasn't vandalising anything; it was set as duplicate and thus I didn't understand the point of maintaining these ideas there; I didn't like the discussion and wanted to transmit it to any reader and you avoid me to do that, this is where the censure came into.

Comment: So in other words, you're taking offense at the very fact that everyone had good intentions and wasn't actually trying to offend you with their actions? Alrighty then.

Comment: Oh my gods, how did you type this out six minutes earlier than me? Granted I'm using Android, but _still_.

Comment: @Emrakul Don't underestimate the power of a real keyboard. Also, I'm a rather fast typist, which doesn't necessarily combine well with my tendency to be prolix. :-)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I don't know why you are saying that. I just said that the answers in my previous question weren't too convincing but this is nothing bad; what is bad is when I intended to do something and without any discussion, someone avoid me to do that, not once, but twice.

Comment: @Cody Fair enough. I typically am as well... I guess not on Android!

Comment: I physically cringed when you brought up Che Guevara as if he was this great revolutionary who was "right." Anyone who knows what he actually did wouldn't in their right minds use him as an example of righteousness.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ I missed the Che Guevara part, who said this when?

Comment: @Null Admittedly, it wasn't an accident. I'm a history major, not comp sci.

Comment: `Aside from all of that, I have a hard time understanding why it shocks you that people are relatively unlikely to approve of brand new revolutionary ideas that go completely against the fabric and foundation of the entire system we have set up here.` this should be put on a plaque somewhere.

Comment: Reversal in 3... 2... 1....

Comment: @varocarbas The point is, by *completely* changing your post you invalidate all the discussion that's been happening. It now makes no sense. Hence it's called "vandalizing".

Comment: @Pekka웃 I wasn't aware that this idea was so revolutionary for the community. I thought that the fact of justifying any action (negatively) affecting others was seen as something acceptable everywhere. Thus, you are right: this kind of immutable truths, not so evident outside the community, should be clearly stated somewhere, with lots of danger signs surrounding it and messages on the lines of "IMPORTANT: never, ever, under absolute any circumstance dare to mention this issue here!!! We know where you live" :)

Comment: @Seth regarding the famous vandalisation, it was just an attempt to make a point: the question was flagged as duplicated, I did have accepted the view of the community (but didn't agree with it, AT ALL), but I wasn't able to delete it; so I just transmitted my impressions in the only way I was allowed to do: "This is pointless". You were able to read the whole discussion anyway and the links pointing to the original content (mine was a mere duplicate). In any case, I did apologise for that (didn't know that this was so important to you, otherwise wouldn't ever have done that).

Comment: @varocarbas it *should* be somewhat evident though. You have to provide for the possibility that a community that has been around for four years and amassed five million questions may have a good reason for why it does things the way it does. While that doesn't mean those things can't and shouldn't be questioned - it's totally okay to do that! - it's hardly constructive to complain when the community rejects the questioning because it's been discussed many times before already. As others have said, never mind though - my first Meta post was at -7 at one point, too. :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks for the support but I think that getting 2 questions out of your first 3 ones below -10 is a pretty bad start (or better, an indication that I should better focus on what I am good at: stackoverflow). Your statement represents the basic idea behind conservative organisations (e.g., church) vs. more improvement-focused ones (e.g., programmers' community). I do agree with it though (and I apologise for my lack of pre-research); on the other hand, if you take a look at my other question (the only one with +1s on it) you would see that even basic parts can be improved.

Comment: @varocarbas `the basic idea behind conservative organisations` with respect, that's bullcrap. The idea you mention isn't being rejected because the organization is "conservative", but because the community sees clear reasons *why the idea wouldn't be an improvement at all*  (a.k.a. "a bad idea"). And I assure you discussing the same idea 300 times gets old in *any* type of organization, too. New feature suggestions are implemented around here all the time

Comment: @Pekka웃 don't get it in the wrong way. What I meant is that your statement was a typical one from a conservative organisation: "community that has been around for four years and amassed five million questions may have a good reason for why it does things the way it does". It might sound bad but the bigger an organisation becomes the most conservative (because they know already how things are done and because they don't want/need to risk). Perhaps my example wasn't the best one (calling someone "church" is kind of offensive, I agree on that).

Comment: @varocarbas church or no church, you imply that this community wants to conserve for conservation's sake, and fears any kind of improvement. That is not why your idea was rejected. It was rejected because requiring a reason for negative voting would not reach the goal you want to reach, and impair one of the central quality control mechanisms on the site.

Comment: @varocarbas Fact is that you showed no research in the request you made. You were urged to read through the history on this very topic before you deleted your first similar request. Requests like the one you've made are welcome, but then at least bring something new to the table. Show that you've done your research and you've taken previous discussions into account. That's not us being conservative, that's us being tired of having to state the same thing over and over again.

Comment: @Pekka웃 OK, all clear.

Comment: @Bart OK, all clear.

Answer (score 8):

Try to understand what happened here from the perspective of the rest of Meta. This may sound a bit harsh, but it's meant in earnest.

You need to separate the votes a question receives and the effort others put into it. The generated responses mostly show that people read your post, and understood what you were saying. At this point, they disagreed with you. Since [voting is different on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), those who strongly disagreed downvoted. Your proposal happens to be one which has been thoroughly discussed many times before.

Now, look at it from the perspective of a Meta user:

- a user posted a question which has been asked many times before
- they disagree with your idea (that's not to say everyone does, but it's clearly the majority)
- the OP doesn't seem to have searched for existing threads
- ==> downvote

Yes, the actual number of downvotes is often entirely arbitrary, but is an estimator for how people feel. Take the downvotes not as people disliking *you*, but the content of your post.

Secondly, editing your post to ask for it to be deleted is strictly prohibited. It is considered edit vandalism, and is not appreciated by the community. That, alone, is why your post was rolled back. Flexo locked this post, but whether it was in response to the edits is not my place to say.

So, my advice sums to this: Think about the perspective of a typical Meta user. We have nothing against you; we simply disagree with your request.

If you want it deleted in the future, flag for moderator attention.

Comment: I didn't ask for it to be deleted, just said that was pointless. Wasn't it? What is the point of a -a lot question flagged as a duplicate? Where, sorry to say, but I didn't find a proper answer (unlikely this time: Cody Gray answer has been really good). One upvote for you by the way.

Comment: @varo Not necessarily. But either way, the content of the post no longer makes sense in the context of the discussion and answers, so should be rolled back. It serves as a marker to others that the community strongly disagrees with you.

Comment: @varo Also, most people typically have a couple posts which are heavily downvoted. Look in any higher-rep Meta user's profile, sort by votes, and go to the last page. [Look, I have one here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175053/merge-the-numerous-language-and-usage-betas) In short, bad ideas happen. Don't get too  hung up on the voting, but instead focus on the discussion you prompt.

Comment: @Emrakul Hey, I am one of the two apparently crazy people who upvoted that!

Comment: Please, don't compare this is a crazy idea! LOL. Thanks for sharing but the reality is that I am not good for that. I am really happy to have posted this question and have seen that I was quite wrong (still don't like the editing without my permission but well...).

Comment: @varocarbas your point was very well stated, if it was almost any different topic, both of your posts would have faired much much better.  You just happen to hit on the single most asked and rejected feature.  And don't let the downvotes discourage you... check out [this guy's downvoted posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?page=88&tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer%20user%3a1).  The cavet is he founded the site, but still, he never tried to delete those posts because the downvotes are very important on Meta.

Comment: You're not the first to rage quit and not the last. Sorry you can't understand what Stack Overflow and/or Meta are for and hope one day you will understand and come back as a contributing member.

Comment: @Sha Little harsh

Comment: @Emrakul didn't intend to sound harsh anyway looks like I wrote on wrong post... guess it's a sign. Oh well!

Answer (score 7):

I would just like to point out something quite relevant:

> as you rightly said, it is my content. I can do whatever I want with it.

...that's true, until you publish it on Stack Exchange. In order for Stack Exchange to publish it, you have to give it a license to do so — and the license Stack Exchange [requires](https://stackexchange.com/legal) doesn't let you do takesies backsies. Emphasis mine:

> You grant Stack Exchange the **perpetual** and **irrevocable** right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, **even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You**.

So no, you do *not* have a right to delete your posts, even if the site occasionally lets you. You waived that right when you clicked on "Post Your Answer" (or "Post Your Question"). Even if you do delete it, it can be undeleted by others.

If you don't like this, this site might not be for you.

Comment: Why I wouldn't like that. This is an irrefutable fact, I cannot like/dislike irrefutable facts, just can accept them or don't live in the real world; and one thing is sure: I do live in the real world every second. BUT, this does imply that censure might exist; the idea of censure: avoiding someone saying freely what he wants.

Comment: @varocarbas Censure is disallowing people from publishing a given type of work _anywhere._ Removing one post from one site is hardly censure: you can still publish it to your blog, or your web site, or any other web site on the internet that wants to host it :)

Comment: You can block me and edit what want I wrote. I haven't ever discussed that; but being able to do something does not imply to actually doing it. And there is where the attitude (what I was doubting about) comes into picture. And a simple: "please, don't do that" (even though you can impose it to me), is the right way to proceed. If you are a policement you can start talking or start shooting; if you decide the second option, I wouldn't like you and, perhaps, you might even got in troubles because nothing is written in stone and the aforementioned text represents just a generic framework.

Comment: @varocarbas That is what I meant by "If you don't like this, this site might not be for you." You _will_ have your posts edited. You _will_ have your posts deleted. You _will_ have others copy your posts on other sites while giving proper attribution. This is done to make sure the site has high quality content and runs smoothly.

Comment: If I didn't use the right word, I apologise about that. I meant the fact of avoiding someone to freely express his opinion; even, in this case, showing a text as written by someone who does not recognise it as applicable anymore. In summary: compelling someone to do something he does not want to do. And you did that. You can discuss for as long as you wish about your right to do such a thing but cannot hide that this is what you actually did.

Comment: @varocarbas I'm sorry, I must've missed the part where somebody kept you at gunpoint from clicking the "delete" button.

Comment: I don't think that forcing someone as the first alternative is something to be proud of, not even logical. If you have this option anyway, use it wisely: talk; if you cannot get anything with talking, impose.

Comment: @varocarbas Perhaps I'm not coming through clearly. I'll try to explain one last time: we cannot force you to click on buttons, so nobody is compelling or forcing anybody. We cannot force you to publish on this site, so no one is censuring anybody. You freely chose to click on the delete button. The site freely chose to decline your request. That is all that happened.

Comment: You shouldn't have missed it because I almost cried :) (kidding... I never cry). See it as you wish. I made my point clear and critised what I considered critic-worthy; and censoring-by-default will always be critic-worhty, IMO. Thanks for the answer though (don't get me wrong: I +1 you).

Comment: @varocarbas I appreciate the voting, but I'd rather you had a clear idea of what's going on. :)

Comment: just as a last clarification, I insist in my first message: I do accept the rules and know that have to accept them. I am not discussing about that. Just that the same rules can be applied in different ways and I have right to critise when I don't think that this application is the right one (shooting before asking, in an extreme scenario) and this is all what I do: use it, respect the rules and, when I don't think that the application is right, complain and critise.

Comment: @varocarbas then let me assure that 99% of the time, all of the edits, all of the closures and all of the deletions that happen or don't happen on the site are made in good faith and are not a personal attack towards you and your own freedoms. It's all either to improve your posts, to improve the answers to your questions, or to improve the site in general. :)

Comment: sorry but apparently cannot be the last one. Please, read this message carefully: I do understand what is legally possible or not (FYI, I have a MS in Law), I do accept the conditions (otherwise, wouldn't be too realistic; this is not something you can discuss with), BUT within the given framework I can (and should) critise when the persons in charge of performing the actions do not act as rightly as should (don't choose the best option): unlikely in your case, I cannot impose what I think, but I can make noise (civil resistance/client is always right, etc.) :)

Comment: I know that you act with good faith!! When I referred bad faith in my post wasn't for the moderators, but for the downvoters (there I saw a bit of bad faith). It is not a question of acting with bad faith, it is a question of not acting as rightly as you should (with the best intention, but wrongly). I think that this has been a long enough discussion. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 6):

I am going to go through your post and try to give my standpoint on the concerns you have mentioned:

---

> I closed the question (the community does not like it = does not belong here = it should be deleted

Just because a question (or an answer) is not liked by the community, doesn't mean it doesn't belong and it also doesn't mean it should be deleted. There are many "unpopular" questions or answers that **need** to stay on the site for their historical significance. You can take a look at some of them by searching for [questions and sorting by votes in reverse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?page=1078&tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion) or the same for [answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?page=1841&tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer). I would say that this opinion is primary seen on meta sites. If a suggestion is made (and suggested in a clear coherent manner), and the community doesn't like the suggestion (for whatever reasons), that suggestion should be kept in order to have somewhere to link to when someone in the future makes the same or a similar suggestion. As long as the answers on that (rejected) suggestion convey *why* the community is opposed there is no reason to start a new discussion and reiterate all the ideas from another discussion.

---

> ...apparently I wasn't welcome (because people asking something which has been asked before is not welcome)

It's nothing personal here. It has nothing to do with you as a user but rather the content of *that specific post*. Duplicates are duplicates and redundant duplicates are redundant. ;) This is why there is a special close reason for duplicates and why an entire system of linking duplicates exists. I feel that here would be a great place to link to the well-known blog post: [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

---

> ...apparently, critics are not welcome...

Have you seen the downvote button? ;) Ok -this one was a little joke :P Onward!

---

> Apparently, requesting justifications when downvoting is not democratic

Is is democratic to **force people** to publicize who/how/what they voted for, and why? Furthermore while the Stack Exchange network might feel like a democracy (of sorts), [the actual truth is quite the different](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/320/what-form-of-government-does-stackexchange-resemble).

---

**About meta** - [Meta is a weird place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta). You have to have quite a thick skin to get by because people are simply not afraid to tell you exactly what they think of your suggestions. In a place like this, you have to be open to the fact that people might not agree with you.

---

A final note about the content you contribute to the site and this is the same no matter which Stack Exchange site you are on: Everything you post (or see) with regard to content is automatically assigned the [Creative Commons Licence](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). It basically means that people are free to do what ever they want with the content as long as attribution is supplied back to the original author. People can and **will** edit your posts. Sometimes, you might not agree with their opinions and changes - this can very quickly turn into an edit war and the lock that the moderator placed was to prevent this exact situation.

The correct way to handle a situation like this one is to leave a comment for the editor (you can reference any editor as you would to any other user, using [@comment replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)). Find out what that user meant by their edits, see if you can find a middle ground on what edits should stay and what edits should be reversed.

Comment: Sorry for being too direct (but has been a really long day of answers). This post was written sarcastically by referring some of the comment in my previous answer. All the ideas are clear (I thought that my update note covered most of the issues, I will re-edit it right now). +1 and thanks for your answer.