# Periods missing from stock bounty notices

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

Some of the default bounty notices are missing periods at the end of the sentence:

[image]

Comment: OH NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO :)

Comment: Due to the severity of this, we'll need to shut down the sites until this is fixed. (:

Comment: May I also suggest that the first notice is not grammatically coherent with the other ones. It doesn't have a subject. How about "This question needs an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources"?

Comment: These were typed in by [Michael Mrozek](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107628/badges-should-reward-positive-behavior/107630#comment277067_107630), weren't they?

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Excellent. I'm glad to see this issue is getting the response and attention it clearly requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushed a fix, now let us all cross our fingers and hope my sync up the table code works.

Comment: to be deployed possibly tomorrow