# Usefulness of Peer Pressure Badge

Tags: discussion, badges, peer-pressure-badge

I realize this has been discussed before, but I still feel the peer-pressure badge in no way promotes good behavior on the site. Look at this [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288014/change-to-the-down-vote-point-system/288016?noredirect=1#comment165434_288016): when I noticed he was deleting all his answers with downvotes, I warned him he could possible get an answer ban if he kept doing the behavior, yet his excuse as to why that is "acceptable" is the fact that the peer pressure badge rewards you for deleting bad answers.

I also read [this request to remove badges that do not encourage positive behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107628/badges-should-reward-positive-behavior) and understand that some badges like peer-pressure are meant to educate the user. I'd feel rewarding a person for doing a discouraged behavior sends the wrong message; yes, everyone makes mistakes and may need to delete some things, but you should not get a reward for it.

In fact, what is the peer pressure badge awarding? Is it rewarding the fact the user wrote a bad answer or decided to delete the bad answer because he or she was getting downvotes.

On the other hand, if we changed **how** they badge is obtained to something along the lines of "Have an answer with a score of -3 and then edit and improve it causing the score to rise to +1", then the badge can stay; I'm just stating that the badge should not be used to reward or even encourage poor conduct or malicious behavior.

I have also read this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231270/please-get-rid-of-the-peer-pressure-badge), and while I agree with some of the points, I feel that this badge causes more harm than benefits.

Comment: Badges are like acheivements in video games. Sometimes you get an achievement for dieing 100 times or something stupid like that.

Comment: Yes, but the badge system is a bit different; in video games, you *don't* have to be told that dieing is not the right way; most people know this from the start; on the other hand, the badge system helps teach people how this site works.

Comment: @Isaiah I've voted to close as dupe (as per link in ShadowWizard comment). While you suggest something different (changing the requirements to obtain the badge), you also discussed getting rid of it too. You'd probs be best posting an answer in the other question suggesting your "change requirements to earn" idea more clearly, than a whole new question.

Comment: @Isaiah you can't delete the question as there is an upvoted answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ummm... Probably no. As said in your second link:

> Generally badges serve two purposes:
>   - Reward the user for doing something right
>   - Compensate the user for losing out in some other area

These sites aren't for bragging how many darn badges you have. What sells you to the community so everyone thinks you're awesome is your rep count. Why do you think Jon Skeet is more popular than me ( a lot more )? Because he has so much rep!

The Peer Pressure badge is to be a award for doing the right thing and deleting a post that may harm the overall quality of our posts. *That* is what the Peer Pressure badge is here for. Deleting lots of answers doesn't mean you use the fact you will earn the Peer Pressure badge as an excuse. ***You can only earn that badge once!***

So there is more benefit than harm and that goes to every other badge.

---

## Extra Info on Other Badges Listed in Second Link

The Disciplined badge on the other hand is like a gift to help you make you feel happier when you lost those rep since you removed a post with a net score of 3. It's like when family helps you up with gifts and such when you suffered something tragic.

Tumbleweed really has the same idea as the Disciplined badge. You ask a question and people don't really look at it and people don't even vote. Won't you be sad? The Tumbleweed is really a badge to lift your spirits. If you start having this a lot, then try improving your questions.

Vox Populi is an award badge that gets awarded because that means, people with that badge are helping to control the overall quality of the posts, seperating the good from the bad.

Really? Struck and White? The fact it is helpful is very clear. End of story.

Taxanomist is a badge that gets awarded because you just made a brand-new tag that will help the current community and future users. No questions asked.

Comment: Just a note -- I only had a problem with peer pressure

Comment: I did say the rest was extra info for badges listed on the other link!