# Downvoting Of questioning or answering

Tags: discussion, down-votes, score, peer-pressure-badge

If I fare badly in questioning or answering. I attract downvotes and hence receive negative scores. In spite of this fact, I have earned the Peer-pressure badge even downvoted. What do you do with total negative scores after taking into account all the scores altogether, which include all questions and answers?

Comment: You earn a Peer Pressure badge specifically for deleting low scoring content.  That's what it's meant to do.  Beyond that, I'm having trouble figuring out what, exactly, you're trying to ask; something about what we do with downvotes?

Comment: Also note that you loose/get back all the rep you gained/lost on downvotes once the post is deleted (with some exceptions for older posts).

Comment: "I have earned Peer-pressure badge even downvoted" could you rephrase that? I don't quite understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: I'm re-opening this because I think I figured out what's going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rolling question rate limits are now network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243460/rolling-question-rate-limits-are-now-network-wide)

Comment: see also: [Usefulness of Peer Pressure Badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251431/165773)

Comment: I have earned the Peer-pressure badge despite being down voted on that question

Comment: fyi, there is no negative score. The minimum is 1

Comment: @AbhijitBagchi I don't see how you're confused. You _can't_ get the Peer pressure badge without being downvoted _multiple times_ on the same post. The 'despite' doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 7):

Okay. I've tried my best to piece together how you've arrived at this question, and this is what I think happened:

- You were tagged / mentioned in a Quora post as being a member of one or more Stack Exchange communities. That may, or may not have been a typo that meant to include you in a discussion related to the *Stock Exchange*.
- You arrived here, saw something similar to Quora, and asked a few philosophical questions not realizing that we're a completely different platform.
- That ... didn't go so well, and you were confused and a little stressed, so you deleted some of the content you wrote because you were worried that it didn't  belong and then...
- Yay! You got a badge! You must have been doing something .. correctly .. the whole time? WHAT IS THIS ODD THING YOU HAVE STUMBLED UPON?

Our similarities with Quora end at us both being a place where people ask and answer questions. We have [a very large network of Q&A sites](https://stackexchange.com) that [work very differently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) than other platforms. It's an interesting coincidence that you arrived here, but we're not what you initially thought :)

What I suggest is, take a look at our network of sites, see if any of them interest you, and perhaps join in on helping people get objective answers to problems they face every day. If you want to debate philosophy or have *discussions*, then Quora is probably where you want to go.

You can use both platforms, and you're very welcome to do so, but take a moment to see how we're different before diving in. Sorry about the confusion, but we were as confused as you were, and all the details are actually in deleted posts which most users can't see, so it wasn't immediately obvious that you were simply out of place :)

Comment: [Usability issues for first-time Stack Exchange users...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279661/165773)

Comment: "If you want to debate philosophy or have discussions, then Quora is probably where you want to go." - or perhaps the chat, if they're willing to invest in getting 20 rep