# Filter titles that only contain tags and/or "filler" words

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, title, quality-filter

Inspired by [this rant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120661/148310) (which listed a couple-dozen question titles with "PHP preg_replace" and nothing else useful in them)<sup>1</sup>, I figured that there may be a practical way to improve the poor title detection.

Pseudo code like this would probably work; test a title-string by:

1. Strip common words and frequent misspellings, EG: `a an and in the teh but not of by to too you u i with for`.
2. Strip numbers, EG: `1234`, `555.867.5309`, etc.
3. Strip "junk words", EG: `about, code, codes, codez, error, errors, exception, exceptions, fault, faults, help, need, porblem, porblems, problem, problems, question, questions, etc.`
4. **Strip tags**, EG: `php preg-replace` and tag variants, EG: `preg_replace pregreplace`.
   If, and only if, junk tags muck this up (it is possible for users to make most any word a tag), then only do this step for tags that have at least, say, 5 questions.
5. Strip single-letter words, EG: `U I J T`, etc.  This will also help in cleaning out the leftover `s` of possessive forms (EG: `PHP's`).
6. If the **resulting string does not contain any word characters** (regex: `\w`), then **the title fails the filter**.

This should help staunch the generation of new, poor question titles.

As a bonus, also create a special review page that lists the existing questions that fail this filter.

As a super-duper bonus, create a new badge, or give some additional reward to users who edit, or correctly flag or successfully close-vote such questions.

---

<sup>1</sup> [**This search** lists a lot of very poor PHP titles, at the moment](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title:PHP%20%2bpreg-replace).

Comment: That last link demonstrates why the words "question", "help", and "problem" don't belong in titles something like 99.999% of the time.