# How can the word "Problem" be used in a question title?

Tags: discussion, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using the word “problem” in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles)
>   [Remove blacklist filter for `problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110789/remove-blacklist-filter-for-problem)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798494/what-are-p-roblem-signatures-about-what-information-can-i-undersdtand-about-the) about "Problem Signatures".

Of course this also applies to other reserved words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, currently, it can't.

It's not really a "reserved word" in the traditional sense—there are no *technical* limitations on using that word in your question title. Rather, there's a word filter in place that intentionally blocks this.

I and several others think that the filter is a bit overzealous and unnecessary. Rather than deterring people from writing bad titles (which it was theorized the word "problem" is a hallmark of), it has just forced people to come up with even less stellar "workarounds", like the one you point to. Many a times, I have tried to edit a post and fix spelling mistakes, only to be told by the system that I actually *can't* spell the word "porblem" correctly. Somewhat self-defeating, I think.

Related:

- [Remove blacklist filter for `problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110789/remove-blacklist-filter-for-problem)
- [Why can't we use the word "problem" in titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles)
- [Let users with sufficient reputation use "problem" in titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108815)
- [The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112944)
- [The Efficacy Of Stack Overflow's Question Title Filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113151/the-efficacy-of-stack-overflows-question-title-filter)
- [Block, but automatically flag "Problem" attempts in the title as "low-quality"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115492/block-but-automatically-flag-problem-attempts-in-the-title-as-low-quality)
- [Filter titles that only contain tags and/or "filler" words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120773/filter-titles-that-only-contain-tags-and-or-filler-words)
- ["Problem" word filter can be circumvented in a search engine compatible way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122172/problem-word-filter-can-be-circumvented-in-a-search-engine-compatible-way)