# Can we have a whitelist of exceptions to the title filter?

Tags: feature-request, title

As has been pointed out previously, the [controversial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so?rq=1) title word filter prevents people like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192515/how-to-ask-about-the-halting-problem-on-stackoverflow-regarding-the-title-fil) from referring to things like the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) in their question titles, which - besides being a frustrating and unpleasant UX to have to work around as a user - makes those questions harder to search for.

It's been made pretty clear that the establishment is strongly in favor of the filter and that [it isn't going to go away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110793/200582) - and that [the filter probably does some genuine good](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113151/200582). That said, can we reach a compromise that keeps the benefits of the filter while removing its major downside? A whitelist of compound terms that include the word 'problem', such as 'halting problem', would make all the harm done by the filter disappear completely and leave only the good.

Comment: Great Meta research, and a good request to boot! Is it April Fool's Day or something?

Comment: Who maintains the white list?  The mods or the devs?  If it's the devs, how do you ask for new white words?  If it's the mods, do you need a new UI to maintain the white list?  Will some grumpy mods simply put "problem" in the white list?

Comment: @Robert - let Josh maintain it, seed it with 95% of what you'd ever need, and let new requests be made in Meta.  If someone chooses to post that "Regex problem" should be added to the whitelist, then he can enjoy his -12 post score.

Comment: Is there any other potential word other than halting you want to add initially ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mathematical_problems seems a pretty good list to start with, @psubsee2003

Comment: @Josh - I never knew computer science could be so morbid... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem

Comment: We could rename that the "One Potato, Two Potato Problem" if it makes you feel better, @AdamRackis. Monty Python managed to combine the two: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJE7uJyHJ3k

Comment: I did a search for "prblm" and a few other misspelled versions.  Sure enough there were dozens of hits in several SE areas.