# Retroactive moderator powers

Tags: feature-request, moderators, vote-to-delete

I just stumbled over [this deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99062/152859). It was deleted by three users, that in the time of deletion were all ordinary users, see the [revisions page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/99062/revisions):

> Post Deleted by animuson♦, Rosinante, Manishearth

(animuson is new moderator, assigned the diamond only very recently)

However when trying to undelete I get the "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted" message.

The point of this is clear, that moderator decision to delete can't be reversed but as mentioned before, he wasn't moderator by the time of deleting the post.

Can this be changed so that moderator power is *not* retroactive?

Comment: In the meantime (since the duplicate says resources aren't going to be devoted to fixing this right now), if you really want it undeleted I suppose flagging is the best option.

Comment: That question is just noise.  There's a reason it was deleted the first time.  What purpose would be served by undeleting it?  Watching the train wreck one more time?

Comment: @Robert, I cannot see that question because it's on meta, but maybe he wants to edit it into shape?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: The title of the post is *"Don't close questions where the user has requested that it not be closed"*.  It's a feature request, with a score of **-151**.  The top answer suggests setting up a migration path to Yahoo! Answers.

Comment: @Robert, I see. All things considered, I'm happy to have less than 10K rep on meta now. Thank you for replying :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Robert forgot to mention that the post in question was a joke. Not a very funny one, but still a valid candidate for framing as historical (like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41976/question-title-that-doesnt-describe-the-problem) or [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)).

Comment: @Rob just thought it would be nice to have it around, can't see any harm in leaving it around, closed anyway. Was also curious to see if the OP would lose the rep again. ;)