# Question body does not match the title

Tags: discussion, questions, title

I came across this question :

[regular expression for title case - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731216/regular-expression-for-title-case-python)

The title was exactly what I was googling for.

But the question body asks about overlapping regex, and not about matching a general title case phrase.

Should I answer the title (since it's what people Google for) or edit it to match the body ?

Comment: [Question title that doesn't describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41976/question-title-that-doesnt-describe-the-problem) - Not a duplicate - just an amusing sidetrack.

Answer (score 6):

The body of a question contains more information than the title, and is more likely to express the true intentions of the OP. A look at the existing answers may also help in determining what is really being asked.

If you ever encounter a *new* question where the body doesn't match the title, it's probably best to ask the author (in a comment) what they really mean; on an old question like this, feel free to (suggest an) edit to make the title match the question body.